# How do I get a power consumption from Linux kernel

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a Linux command I can get the power usage from Linux kernel. For example, I could get a CPU usage from *proc/stat*. I was wondering if there might be a similar command that I could get a power consumption or I could calculate the power consumption from some numbers.

I basically want to measure the power consumption of Android device. I know I could get the battery level of an Android device but I want to measure POWER consumption not just battery level.

I tried the PowerProfile, a private API, but I was not able to run it on my project.

Comment: have u successfully achieved your task ?